# Randomly creating a sets of 2 numbers from a list that contains list of numbers

Tags: python, random, set

So the problem im having is that I have a list that contains multiple lists (like a group divided to smaller subgroups with even size) and I need to randomly match 2 numbers and make them a set without repetition. The matching can be within the same subgroup or from other subgroup but the most important part is that you cant use the same number more than once.

So at first I used NumPy for random permutation of the numbers and then reshape for dividing it to subgroups in the size I want:

```
arr = np.random.permutation(40).reshape(10, 4) #numers for example
```

The part of the matching is the part that I cannot understand, I tried to look it up but didnt found somthing that helped my situation.

Example:

- Input: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`
- Expected output: random pairs like `[(1,5),(2,3),(4,6)]`

Comment: Could you provide some sample input and expected outputs?

Comment: So basically you need to split the list of lists randomly into list of list of 2 elements?

Comment: yeah that sounds about right, but without changing the original list

Comment: I'd first flatten the list and make a collections.Counter from it, then randomly match the value with the highest counter with any other value, rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

One approach can be to flatten the list, shuffle it and then split into chunks of needed size:

```py
arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [42,555, 777]]
flattened_list = [item for sublist in arr for item in sublist]
np.random.shuffle(flattened_list)

def chunk(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

result = list(chunk(flattened_list, 2))
print(result) # sample output - [[555, 3], [2, 1], [42, 5], [777, 4]]
```

Tuple version can look like the following:

```py
# ...
np.random.shuffle(flattened_list)
it = iter(flattened_list)
result = [*zip(it, it)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure Python solution (i.e. without Numpy) would be

```py
import random

l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
# Flatten sublists
flat_l = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
# Shuffle elements in flattened list (in-place)
random.shuffle(flat_l) 
# Create two-tuples by pairing elements in 1st and 2nd half of shuffled list
len_half = len(flat_l) // 2
result = [*zip(flat_l[:len_half], flat_l[len_half:])]
```